# Enable tail-call optimization in Agda

Tags: agda

I'm using Emacs with `agda-mode`, and have written this function:

```
pow : Nat → Nat → Nat
pow m n = pow' 1 m n
          where
            pow' : Nat → Nat → Nat → Nat
            pow' acc _ zero = acc
            pow' acc m (succ n) = pow' (m * acc) m n
```

`Nat`, `succ` and `*` are defined to be compatible with Agda's internal definitions of natural numbers.

When I evaluate `(pow 2 100000)` I get a stack overflow error. However, given that the recursive call is a tail call, I would like the agda interpreter to optimize `pow'` into a loop.

How can I enable this optimization?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't; perhaps you might want to compile the code.

Comment: The "internal definitions of natural numbers" apply mostly when compiling, not in the evaluator. If you run `pow 2 100000` in C-c C-n, you're going to get a unary natural that's uses more memory than there are atoms in the universe. If you want something like this to be usable for proofs and interpretation, use `Data.Bin` in the standard library.

Comment: `pow 2 10000` does work nicely, so it's probably also using the builtin definitions when using C-c C-n. 

Data.Bin looks interesting; though I also get stack overflows with that.

Compiling with MAlonzo could solve the issue, but I'd really like to work in interactive mode.

Comment: File a ticket (or mailing list post) asking for some notion of tail call in the evaluator then?

Comment: I just filed a [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/detail?id=912&thanks=912&ts=1380104094). I'll post an answer when I get some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This optimisation is not implemented in the current version of Agda. Alternatives include increasing the size of the stack, or rewriting the recursion to be logarithmic in the exponent, not linear.

I have also been told that:

> There is ongoing work to deeply change the Agda.TypeChecking.Reduce
>   module (among others), which hopefully would have a positive impact on
>   recursion over builtin naturals as well.

[Ticket](https://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/detail?id=912) on the issue tracker.

Comment: This answer should hopefully be updated in the future, as development advances.